# Laravel - Modify DB::connection method

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I want to modify DB::connection so if I am running tests it will override a given connection.

I have lots of hard-coded connections in the models like this DB::connection('mysql2') so I want to override the mysql2 connection with mysql_testing.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Don't do this. The `phpunit.xml` file lets you override any `.env` values while running tests, via stuff like `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`. Override the `DB_CONNECTION` environment variable and have at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is adding in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
```

Then in `config/database.php` I create duplicate of `mysql` connection something like this:

```
'mysql_testing' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_TESTING_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_TESTING_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_TESTING_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_TESTING_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
],
```

and then in `.env` I define testing connection settings:

```
#TESTING

DB_TESTING_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_TESTING_DATABASE=test_database
DB_TESTING_USERNAME=root
DB_TESTING_PASSWORD=pass
```

It's working without any problems plus you don't need to switch anything in `.env` if you are running tests and testing application manually on same machine/in same directory

**EDIT**

If you have situation like this, probably modifying multiple models is not the best way but if you want to use same database regardless of connection set you can do something like that:

Assuming you have set environment to testing what can be done using:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

in your `phpunit.xml` file you can do go into your `AppServiceProvider` class and in `register` method do something like this:

```
if ($this->app->environment('testing')) {
    $this->app['config']->set('database.connections.mysql2.database', 'yourcustom testing database');
    // ... 
    $this->app['config']->set('database.connections.mysql15.database', 'yourcustom testing database');
}
```

I haven't tried it but it should work - it should make that when running tests you can set all your connections to same testing database (or to other databases if you wish)

Comment: The problem with that is I have lots of hard-coded connections in the models like this DB::connection('mysql2') so I want to override the mysql2 connection with mysql_testing which won't work by just setting it in phpunit.xml

Comment: Won't that only set the connection until  DB::connection('mysql2')  is called?

Comment: What do you mean? When you use it, it should connect to database you set in service provider. So if in your model you are using this connection mysql2 and and in service provider you set it to different database this different database should be used

Comment: I see now, I think that will work. Need to give it a test.

Comment: @Jack I'd handle `mysql2` by having a `DB2_CONNECTION` `.env` value. Make it configurable, which lets you override that config for testing.